# How can I disable the user input in a entry box, in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, widget, python-3.8

I am developing a **Random Password Generator Application**, in which I am using a **entry box** to show the password which will be randomly generated. I want to insert only the password but disable the ablity of the user type inside the entry box but the user can select and copy the contents of the entry box.
Please help me with this problem..

This is not the exact code which I am using in my application, but the concept is the same. I am posting this code for reference. Now I want to disable the ablity of the user to type inside the entry1 entrybox but still i want to pass the randomly generated password inside the entry1 entrybox.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string
import pyperclip

root = Tk()
# BackEnd

def copy_to_clipbrd():
    pyperclip.copy(entry1.get())

def password():
    random_password = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 15)
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry1.insert(0, random_password)


# FrontEnd
entry1 = Entry(root,width = 40, borderwidth = 20 )
entry1.place(x = 50, y = 35)
btn1 = Button(root, text = "Generate", command = password)
btn1.place(x = 70, y = 45)
btn2 = Button(root, text = "Copy", command = copy_to_clipbrd)
btn2.place(x = 85, y = 45)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post what you've have done to get assistance

Comment: You can use a `Label` instead.

Comment: I think there is nothing specific code to post. Though my front-end is ready, I can provide that code but what is the need of that code? I tried disabling the entry box, and it disabled  it but, I cannot pass any information into the entrybox now. I can share that code if it is needed. Before trying the entry box I tried label but it is not useful in this situation since password length may vary. Say, if the length is about 30 or something, then it will become problematic to show that on a screen which is about "520x470" and screen also has other options which take up space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the entry widget before you insert the data in the entry `entry1.config(state="normal")` after that then you `disable` by doing it this way  `entry1.config(state="disable")` it so you cannot type in the `entry`.

**FULL CODE**

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string
import pyperclip

root = Tk()
# BackEnd

def copy_to_clipbrd():
    pyperclip.copy(entry1.get())

def password():
    entry1.config(state="normal")
    random_password = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 15)
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry1.insert(0, random_password)
    entry1.config(state="disable")


# FrontEnd
entry1 = Entry(root,width = 40, borderwidth = 20 )
entry1.place(x = 50, y = 35)
btn1 = Button(root, text = "Generate", command = password)
btn1.place(x = 70, y = 85)
btn2 = Button(root, text = "Copy", command = copy_to_clipbrd)
btn2.place(x = 145, y = 85)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @ShivanshMishra Glad to help.